# Prove that there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(c)|>2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f(k)=1$ for some $k\in (0,1)$. Prove that there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(c)|>2$

I tried the taylor expansion of $f$ at $x=k$,ie $f(x) = f(k) + f'(\xi)(x-k) = 1+f'(\xi)(x-k)$.

$f(0) = 1+ f'(\xi_0)(-k) = 1+ f'(\xi_1)(1-k) = f(1) = 0$

But i am not sure how to show the desired inequality. Any hints?

Comment: You might use the mean value theorem.

Comment: I would try MVT

Comment: hmm im not sure what function i should use MVT on, its probably not on f and the intervals [0,k] and [k,1], right?

Comment: Do you mean $|f'(c)| \geq 2$?

Comment: @Gibbs I don't think so, perhaps you have some counterexamples in mind?

Comment: @Timothy k will be the point of local maxima in (0,1) with value as 1. The graph itself will serve as the proof.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL i dont see how k must always be a local maxima

Comment: No counterexamples in mind, the statement seems quite intuitive.

Comment: @Timothy as the function is continuous in (0,1) and f(0)=f(1)=0 , the function will take f(x)=y for two values of x in (0,1) expect for local maxima which is as question states k in this case as f(x)=1 for only one value of x=k, k must be the local maxima.

Comment: @Gibbs look at my answer, it is $>$, not $\ge$

Answer (score 5):

Use the mean value theorem:

$$f'(c_0)=\frac{f(k)-f(0)}{k-0}=\frac{1}{k}\\f'(c_1)=\frac{f(1)-f(k)}{1-k}=\frac{-1}{1-k}$$
Now, there are 3 cases: $\begin{cases}k\in(0,\frac12)\\k=\frac12\\k\in(\frac12,1)\end{cases}$

---

In case 1, $f'(c_0)>\frac1{\frac12}=2$

---

In case 3, $f'(c_1)<-\frac1{1-\frac12}=-2\implies |f'(c_1)|>2$

---

In case 2, both $f'(c_0),|f'(c_1)|$ are equal to 2, if every point between $0$ to $k$ and between $k$ to $1$ has slope of $2$ in one side and $-2$ in the other then $f'(k)$ is undefined​, so I know that it can't be, but I also know that the average is $2$ in one side and $-2$ in the other, I know that because the average value of a function is: $$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b g(x) dx$$ put in this $b=\frac12,a=0$ or $b=1, a=\frac12$, and $g(x)=f'(x)$ and you will get $2$ or $-2$

So there exist at leas one point between $0$ and $k$ that has slope is greater than $2$ and at least one point between $k$ and $1$ that has slope that is less than $-2$

Comment: I can see that "the average is or −2−2" is pretty intuitive but is there a more precise way of phrasing it?

Comment: @Timothy I added it to the answer

Comment: We can handle the second case without using integrals. See my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i understand this but i still think that using average like this is easier, the integral may look like it require some work but all it really says is that the average slope is the slope of the line that pass through the endpoints. computing it is really easy

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the integral approach but it requires the derivative $f'$ to be integrable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ain't $f$ being differentiable implies that?

Comment: No it does not imply that.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to dispose of the cases $k<1/2$ and $k>1/2$ using the equations $$f(0)+kf'(c_{1})=f(k)=1=f(k)=f(1)+(k-1)f'(c_{2})$$ The case when $k=1/2$ requires a bit more analysis. If $f'(1/2)>0$ then there is a point $k'>1/2$ such that $f(k') >f(1/2)=1$ and then $$1<f(k')=f(1)+(k'-1)f'(c_{3})$$ so that $|f'(c_{3})|>2$. Similarly we can deal with the case $f'(1/2)<0$.

Let's consider the case when $f'(1/2)=0$ and $f(1/2)=1$ is the maximum value of $f$ in $[0,1]$. If $f'(c) \leq 2$ for all $c\in(0,1/2)$ then we can see that $$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(c)\leq 2x,f(x)=f(1/2)+(x-1/2)f'(d)\geq 1+2(x-1/2)=2x$$ so that $f(x) =2x$ for all $x\in[0,1/2]$ and this contradicts $f'(1/2)=0$. Thus we must have some point $c\in(0,1/2)$ for which $f'(c) >2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how $f(x) \ge 2x$ since $f'(d) /le 2$. Can you elaborate on it please?

Comment: @Timothy: $f'(d) \leq 2$ and multiply this with negative number (actually non-positive number) $(x-1/2)$ then the inequality is reversed.